# Problem upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I had been running Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer which I had stopped using for a while due to some circumstances that required it to be so. I was finally able to begin using it again, but I wanted the computer to have the latest Ubuntu 20.04 release. I booted it up and upgraded the packages to the latest releases using apt-get.  Everything went well, so I decided to use `update-manager` to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 by issuing the command `update-manager -c -d 2>&1 | tee /root/"20.04 Upgrade Output.txt"` as root.

The upgrade process progressed fine and it asked me to confirm some packages that needed to be restarted because of the `libc` package upgrade.  After I confirmed, I left and came back to find an error at the command-line that I don’t understand.  I tried to reissue the `update-manager` command twice.  Each time I got the same error. I don't understand the error and I don't know what to do to complete the upgrade.  I shutdown the computer without proceeding any further. I was able to download the Ubuntu 20.04 iso image and burn it to a DVD, but I have not tried to do anything with the computer at all. I uploaded the log file to which I had all the output redirected to my Box account and created a link which I am including below. The `loading .desktop file` errors did not cause any crashes. The final `double free detected` error is the one at which the crash occurs. How can I complete the upgrade successfully?

As I replied to the first comment, I have managed to `chroot` into the system just fine using the information in this link [LiveCD Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) (under the title “Update Failure”).  I can issue commands fine.  I am attaching the `/var/log/dpkg.log` file and the `/var/log/apt/history.log` files.  The dates in the log files don’t seem to be right (maybe the computer clock was not set right), but I’m pretty sure the logs are relevant to the upgrade.  Maybe now there is some way to get `apt-get` to resume the upgrade?

I am also attaching the `/var/log/apt/term.log` file with the other log files that I have attached.

https://app.box.com/s/bztzwo352vq2l1czxd8ihcrno87f53c7
[/var/log/dpkg.log](https://app.box.com/s/llqhhdu5uwtn8invm3xv7t2m7wanx7su)
[/var/log/apt/history.log](https://app.box.com/s/wjrvg8et2lx2j9067irpmlir2puxu2hk)
[/var/log/apt/term.log](https://app.box.com/s/z1xb7yisjwl8x186c1t42o1c86s7zx7y)

```
[06:45][root@jose-desktop: ~]# update-manager -c -d 2>&1 | tee /root/"20.04 Upgrade Output.txt"
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/ardour:ardour.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/bluedevil:bluedevil-monolithic.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/five-or-more.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/five-or-more:five-or-more.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/four-in-a-row.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/four-in-a-row:four-in-a-row.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gbrainy.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gbrainy:gbrainy.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gnome-chess.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-chess:gnome-chess.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gnome-klotski.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-klotski:gnome-klotski.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gnome-mahjongg.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-mahjongg:gnome-mahjongg.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gnome-mines.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-mines:gnome-mines.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nibbles.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-nibbles:gnome-nibbles.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gnome-robots.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-robots:gnome-robots.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gnome-sudoku.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-sudoku:gnome-sudoku.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/gnome-tetravex.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-tetravex:gnome-tetravex.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-user-share:gnome-user-share-properties.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/gparted:gparted.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Hitori.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/hitori:hitori.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/iagno.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/iagno:iagno.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/imagemagick-6.q16:display-im6.q16.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/kio:kmailservice5.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/openshot:openshot.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/quadrapassel.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/quadrapassel:quadrapassel.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/tali.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/tali:tali.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/vino:vino-preferences.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/xboard-config.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/xboard-fen-viewer.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/xboard-pgn-viewer.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/xboard-tourney.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/xboard.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/xboard:xboard-fen-viewer.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/xboard:xboard.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/xboard:xboard-config.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/xboard:xboard-pgn-viewer.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/xboard:xboard-tourney.desktop: constructor returned NULL
WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/app-install/desktop/xjadeo:xjadeo.desktop: constructor returned NULL
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Using the information in this link [1] (in the section “Update Failure”), I am able to chroot into the system, move around in the filesystem, and issue commands as if I were in the system just fine.  I went into the /var/log directory and was able to see the dpkg.log file and the apt/history.log file.  I will try to attach them somehow (If it is possible, I will edit the question and attach the files that way).  I wonder if it is possible to get apt-get to resume with some command.  Maybe it is possible to resume the upgrade somehow. [1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1238355/968501

Comment: Thanks. I did try to follow the instructions, but stopped short of accepting the final upgrade prompt because I could not see clearly which packages would be removed, etc. I found that the computer could be booted up so I decided to boot it up and  try using synaptic for the upgrade because I trust its decisions. When I chose a full upgrade, it presented me with the same packages to be removed, installed, etc. as when I first ran update-manager so I accepted. Everything seemed to be okay, but it also crashed.  Now the system is unstable, but I will try to fix it as best I can.  Thanks again.