# Cannot boot after update!

Tags: boot, updates

I tried to update my system as suggested from the system itself, after reboot I got this error message and cannot continue:

```
loading linux 4.4.0-21-generic 
error: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic has invalid signature. 
loading initial ramdisk ... 
alloc magic is broken at 0x47d081e0: 47ba4f80 
Aborted. Press any key to exit
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which flavor and version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Looks like an interrupted or failed upgrade. Probably try to [fix this failed upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393/968501)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a misconfigured Grub boot loader. If you have a bootable Ubuntu installation disc or USB stick, boot from there. Choose “Try Ubuntu” to boot into the live desktop environment. From there, Ubuntu will automatically detect the messed up Grub configuration and present a wizard to help you fix it. Follow the steps and, so long as there is no hardware failure causing the issue, you’ll be good to go.

The kernel version you reported is for Ubuntu 16.04. If you don’t have a bootable disc or USB stick for 16.04, you can use one for 20.04 or 20.10 safely without losing any of your data. Just remember to choose “Try Ubuntu”, not “Install”

Hope this helps.