# Ubuntu won't start after upgrading to 20.10: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.10

I just tried to update my ubuntu from 20.04 to 20.10. It seemed to crash during the update and when my PC restarted, the screen is blank apart from the cursor and occasional flashing messages which say

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: clean, 969757/62512152 files, 235279954/250050816 blocks
[FAILED] Failed to start process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
```

I booted into grub menu > recovery mode > fsck and then the following screen happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hzHL.jpg

I then ran `systemtcl status apport-autoreport.service` in the root grub menu and got:

```
systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.services: Start request repeated too quickly
systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.services: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'
systemd[1]: Failed to start process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
```

And I am now not sure where to go.

Sorry I normally copy and paste error messages in but I couldn't copy or paste here.

**EDIT**

`ls -al /var/crash`
[image]

`systemctl --failed`
[image]

`systemctl status apport-autoreport.path`
[image]

`systemctl status apport-autoreport.service`
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed ubuntu 20.04 installation upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-ubuntu-20-04-installation-upgrade)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `systemctl --failed` and `systemctl status apport-autoreport.path` and `systemctl status apport-autoreport.service`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema have added - apologies about the poor images - I tried to change the resolution of the grub menu but couldn't manage it.

Comment: @Raffa thanks for the pointer - I will make a bootable USB and try the advice there.

Comment: At the GRUB menu, try and boot to an older kernel. If that works, then re-run `Software Updater`. If that doesn't work, reinstall Ubuntu from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: @heynnema Yes this worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the GRUB menu, try and boot to an older kernel. If that works, then re-run `Software Updater`. If that doesn't work, reinstall Ubuntu from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: This worked by doing the above (entering into root shell prompt) and then running ```sudo apt-get update```.```sudo apt-get upgrade```,```sudo apt-get dist-upgrade``` and rebooting.

Comment: @user438383 Thanks for the detailed update! Good job!