# Ubuntu 18.04: Boot Multiple Errors persist even after correction

Tags: boot, 18.04

Yesterday I had launched the automatic update suggested by Ubuntu updater, but didn't restart the system.

Today, when I tried to start it, the system freezes at the boot, so I went into the safe mode, tried the dpkg option first. Then restated the system, still the same problem.

After, I went into the safe mode again and tried to go into the log file, so I entered the command line: `journalctl -p 3 -xb`, and I obtained the following output.

I already searched the solutions of these error messages, and tried some of the proposed solutions, but still the problem persists, and more than that, it seems that the errors remain the same even.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance.

Here are the error messages that I got.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed ubuntu 20.04 installation upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-ubuntu-20-04-installation-upgrade)

Comment: It seems your update was interrupted or failed for some reason. You can however attempt to fix it by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393/968501). Alternatively if you do not have a live USB/CD, you can try booting to an older kernel and if it succeeds and you could login to your system then you can run update again.

Comment: Yes, I did create a bootable Ubuntu USB key of the same release version (18.04.5 LTS), so I think I will proceed this way. Thank you!