# Update failed not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates, 20.10

Hey I'm a noob in Linux and I just updated to Ubuntu 20.10 when updated I rebooted the system but instead of booting it is waiting but nothing happens..
When I googled it was answered as it is not completely installed so I should update it by opening older Linux version using grub and then update it..
But when I opened the older version it instead showed me a blank screen where I cannot do anything.. it does not show me any background or icons and when I tried to open terminal it does not open..
Now what should I do

I have a dual boot Windows 10 Ubuntu system and was updated from Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 "Please update the microcode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-upgrade-from-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-04-please-update-the-microcode)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments everyone! But I think I found the Solution.
I tried going to previous versions i.e. 20.04 recovery mode and then first enabled networking and then repaired broken packages and updated grub.
then on the next restart I go to 20.10's recovery mode and did the same.
this then helped me to open the UI for ubuntu where i updated my packages as usual and it worked great..