# How to complete upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Nearing completion of an upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, my Dell desktop computer's screen and keyboard froze.  Shortly before that, the computer asked me to close all applications in preparation for rebooting.  A column of icons on the left side of the screen indicated with red dots the active applications.  I successfully closed all but two of these active application icons.  The remaining two were instances of the same icon: a light-gray circle formed by counter-clockwise arrows enclosing a capital "A".  The first seemed unrelated to the upgrade process, so I closed it. (Its red dot disappeared.) The second icon is related to the completing the upgrade.  After I closed the first of those two icons, the screen and keyboard froze.  I thought of rebooting but then found (via an internet search on another computer) a strong recommendation to never reboot before seeing evidence that an upgrade had finished.  Now I do not know how to finish the upgrade.  Please suggest what needs to be done to complete the upgrade.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 "Please update the microcode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-upgrade-from-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-04-please-update-the-microcode)