# 18.04 LTS update failure, crashed my system. Can't acces SSD files

Tags: boot, updates, xubuntu, crash

Tried to update 18.04 system via "Software Update Tool" but it crashed halfway with message "Your Software Update Tool have been corrupted please reinstall for further use" or smth like that.
After that the system crashed and I can only access my grub menu. Entering Recovery mode kicks me into initramfs screen (normal boot shows only blackscreen, no splash or code info)

Initramfs ask for fsck on dev/sda5 (where Xubuntu system resides) but when doing so it simply return error with "no such directory"

[image]

From Live CD session I figured out that there is no way I can access my SSD disk (sda) data, where are my system files resides (WINDOWS sda1 and Xubuntu sda5 - dual boot). I could only acces my HDD (sdb) with "home" directory and swap partition.

Gparted pop-up error:

`Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda1 ...dev/sda5: input/output error`

Dmesg returns error:

```
[   93.932244] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0d 7b 2c a8 00 00 08 00
[   93.932246] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 226176168 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   93.932249] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2097301, lost async page write
```

My question:

1. Could I simply access somehow my left data from sda1 (some personal files from Windows in SSD).
2. Or if that's possible repair broken system (possibly corrupted packages).

BTW. Installer of Ubuntu doesn't reads SSD either, so I can't reinstall my system.

SATA set to AHCI in BIOS

Please help

---

EDIT 1:
Code log below from booting into recovery mode and crashing to initramfs

```
ata1.000: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.000: cmd 61/08:a8:08:44:3b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 4096 out
          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata1.000: status { DRDY }
ata1.000: hard resetting link
ata1.000: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata1.000: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
```

....repeating several times above error and then:

```
fsck.ext4: Input/output error while trying to re-open /dev/sda5

/dev/sda5: ******* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors ********
fsck exited with status code 12
done
Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed
The root filesystem ob /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built in-shell (ash)

(initramfs)_
```

Can not perform manual fsck on /dev/sda5 cuz of INPUT/OUTPUT error on SSD

*) My disk specification on laptop

- /sda: SSD with Dual-boot (sda1: Windows 8.1 ; sda5: Xubuntu 18.4)
- /sdb: HDD with home and swap partition + other space partitions

Can acces /sdb/ but can not acces data od /sda/ now

---

EDIT 2
`Testdisk` detects my SSD properly but doesn't detect my sda partitions table

---

EDIT 3
`sudo fdisk -l` doesn't show my sda partitions
`sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/` gives error: `can't read superblock on /dev/sda5`

Comment: You are still using fsck.ext2? I would try to repair it (with a live USB) - `man fsck` will help you

Comment: Manual fsck doesn't work cuz it can't detect sda drive

Comment: Since you changed your hdd for an ssd one. Check that the stata connector is correctly connected to your motherboard.

Comment: Yes, done that. Anyway it was working perfectly for over 2 years after changing for SSD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 "Please update the microcode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-upgrade-from-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-04-please-update-the-microcode)

Comment: Sorry Raffa, ```sudo mount /dev/sda``` can't read superblock on /dev/sda thus can't mount it