# Ubuntu not booting after upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, upgrade, initramfs, busybox

I upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04 from 18.04. But after the upgrade I'm having trouble booting my system. I'm getting the following message displayed:

```
**/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: error while loading shared libraries: liblzma.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=................................ does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)**
```

I tried a few solutions from various forums that involved booting with a live USB stick, but nothing worked. Please somebody suggest how to rescue this. I'm really falling behind with my work.

Ubuntu is installed on sdb4.

Comment: May be an interrupted upgrade [try fixing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-upgrade-from-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-04-please-update-the-microcode/1238393#1238393) also check your HDD and make sure it is still alive. But most likely interrupted upgrade.

Comment: HDD seems to be okay as other partitions (NTFS) on the same HDD are readable when Windows is booted from the SSD. I'll try out your linked answer and get back to you. Many thanks.

Comment: @Raffa You are a life saver buddy. Followed your instructions and got the upgrade fixed. Although many other forum posts suggested along the similar lines but your solution was complete. However I'm facing display manager related issues now. If you have any ideas regarding [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314932/display-managers-gdm3-xdm-not-working-after-upgrade-to-20-04-lightdm-stuck-in), it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is what I used to fix the broken upgrade issue, but unfortunately it didn't help with the display manager issue.