# Display Managers gdm3, xdm not working after upgrade to 20.04; lightdm stuck in login loop, only LXDE working

Tags: 20.04, login, lightdm, gdm, lxde

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. But I'm now stuck with problems with display managers.

GDM3 (preferred DM for me) and xdm are just stuck at a black screen (with a blinking cursor/underscore).

Next idea was to start in recovery mode and try lightdm, which finally leads me to the login screen.

Just as I think my problems are gone and enter my login credentials at the login screen, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back. This keeps on happening for all desktop environment options except LXDE and Openbox.

I tried looking at answers provided for similar issues but they didn't work. Some had suggested

**sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop**

But I don't think it's installed in the first place for me as I get:

**Unable to locate package chrome-remote-desktop**

If someone could help me by giving out a few pointers, that'll be really helpful.

Comment: What is your video card, is it NVIDIA? If yes, [try this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501)

Comment: What desktops do you have installed?  You only mention one (LXDE) which you say works.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226008/968501) also is related and can help.

Comment: @Raffa Yes my card is NVIDIA but I somehow doubt the linked solution will work. The reason being I didn't have any NVIDIA drivers installed initially, only nouveau driver. But then also, this problem was persisting. I have only recently installed an older (stable) NVIDIA driver (390) to get my resolution up. Earlier it was stuck at around 600X400 with nouveau.

Comment: @guiverc The other ones are GNOME Classic, Openbox, Ubuntu (Default) and Ubuntu on Wayland

Comment: @Raffa So for the second linked solution, the output to **sudo systemctl status gdm** is **● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)**
ubuntu-desktop was already installed to the latest version, I just reinstalled it as you had suggested.

Comment: Then the second linked solution is what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119534/discussion-between-averis007-and-raffa).

Comment: I would however give the first linked solution a shot if the second linked one didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the linked solutions worked. I have tried using kubuntu also. [This](https://pastebin.com/Akkb7L8M) is the crash report, if it can help.