# Turned off PC while upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, do-release-upgrade

I was upgrading xubuntu. It was taking quite a while and I went away from pc. When I came back I saw a new desktop and there were no windows opened and panel didn't work too. Opening folders gave error that some file didn't exist (I don't remember exactly which)

So I decided to restart the PC and while it was turning off I saw the installation window and realized that the installation process wasn't actually finished.

Now when I turn on PC, after xubuntu logo there are only black screen, static text line on the top-left corner and cursor appearing and disappearing every 3 seconds. I can't even open tty.

Comment: I would not try and login to your GUI until the upgrade process has fully completed.  I would firstly boot *live* media to `fsck` your system (I do that if ever I lose power or any unclean shutdown and non-clean shutdown), then boot & login to TTY (text terminal) and `sudo apt update` (very and check everything looks good) then `sudo apt full-upgrade` and wait until completed...   I'd follow any suggestions it makes, then once all completed; then I'd reboot & expect the system to boot normally into the new upgraded OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 "Please update the microcode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-upgrade-from-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-04-please-update-the-microcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot reach any shell prompt, then it's time to reinstall Ubuntu.

A release-upgrade is when your system is most vulnerable -- it takes time for the two incompatible sets of packages to be exchanged by apt. Interrupting a release-upgrade may leave a system with two incomplete sets of incompatible packages...you are lucky if it boots at all. It's an easy way for unaware users to damage their system beyond recovery. Sometimes the system can be rescued, sometimes it cannot.