# Upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10 interrupted and cannot get to recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, lvm, do-release-upgrade, recovery-mode

When I choose the recovery mode option in grub, I get a blinking screen with the below message:

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 120: /lib/recovery-mode/options/whiptail:: No such file or directory
```

Any clue?

What I tried so far:
Loaded a live usb, chroot to the root partition and run `dpkg --reconfigure -a` and some apt commands. No luck.

My home directory is in the same partition as root which is a lvm partition. If it is possible to reinstall without affecting /home, I would go with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 "Please update the microcode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-upgrade-from-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-04-please-update-the-microcode)

Comment: While in chroot you have to try reinstalling [recovery package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=recovery-mode%2Frecovery-menu&mode=exactfilename&suite=impish&arch=any) by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall friendly-recovery` and then reboot to recovery again.

Answer (score 3):

I actually had the same problem while upgrading. The comment by @Raffa actually helped a lot. I had to apply some small changes, though.

After running a live distro, I opened a shell and followed these steps:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/(your partition id) /mnt/
sudo mount --bind /proc/ /mnt/proc/
sudo mount --bind /sys/ /mnt/sys/
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
sudo chroot /mnt/
```

Then I continued like this:

```
sudo mv /etc/ld.so.preload /etc/ld.so.preload.old
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt upgrade
```

I hope that will help!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I attempted to update from  Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
I used the steps provided above by Francesco Alagna, however, once I got to the step of running "sudo dpkg --configure -a", I got an error message below:

```
sudo: symbol lookup error /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so: undefined symbol _dl_sym
```

and I had to do an additional step which I found here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469692&p=14092862#post14092862

> 

You can boot from a "Ubuntu Live cd/usb" and remove de files /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so*, and remove or comment line "/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so" in the file /etc/ld.so.preload"
After that reboot and login again.
When you still see errors about /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so, just execute ldconfig as root.

> Blockquote

Then after that step I continued the steps provided above by Francesco Alagna.  Thank you for saving my system!
Matt