# Broke my Linux again! 

Tags: lightdm

Posted byu/H0tch33tos
just now

Broke my Linux again! 
I'm kinda new in the Linux World, so I've been using it for a month now, I'm loving it so far, but can't stop messing around with it lol. I have dual boot Ubuntu21.04 - Windows 11 (just like to have the lastest and bleeding edge software sometimes).

I was trying to customize my LightDm theme but I completely broke the sys. I changed to LihgtDm-webkit2-greeter, saw some good-looking themes here: lightdm-webkit2-greeter-theme · GitHub Topics · GitHub and decided to download one. I installed this one: GitHub - Demonstrandum/Saluto: Saluto — A WebKit LightDM Theme , put this into the lightdm-webkit2-greeter.conf file:

*"[greeter]
webkit_theme=saluto"*

And then decided to reboot ._. (It was 3 AM, I can justify my stupidity) and from that all went to hell.

First issue: FAILED TO START LIGHTDM MANAGER

**A PHOTO OF IT**
[FAILED TO START LIGHTDM MANAGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXMnZ.jpg)

If I just turn the PC on, select Ubuntu in the Dual-Boot and do nothing, it just stays in the GUI screen only showing Aorus logo with Ubuntu logo as well charging but never going anywhere:[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdsv9.jpg)

I tried to launch TTY to fix this issue but none of combs are working for me, only place a can go and actually do something is to the grub. But I press Ctrl+Alt+F1-7 and nothing happens, will explain behavior of each one below:

**Ctrl+Alt+F1:** Just prompted me GUI screen I showed in the pic before. When I just press F1 it sends me to the detailed screen in the first pic.

**Ctrl+Alt+F2:** Don't send me anywhere, sometimes it actually sends me to a complete blackscreen with just a blinking underscore in the top-left corener of the screen, no prompt from terminal, not able to write anything.

**from Ctrl+Alt+F2** to Ctrl+Alt+F5: same behavior, just the blinking guy.

**Ctrl+Alt+F6:** Is the only one that actually allows me to write. But no prompt or can't run any command. [Blackscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcNfH.jpg)

**Ctrl+Alt+F7:** Is the only one that shows me something but can't write or run anything neither. [Ctrl+Alt+F7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrsUc.jpg)

I haven't found yet a way to open TTY, I think I can fix it from there by my own but can't go anywhere from there.

Comment: Stop the boot at grub, enter recovery mode, enable networking, drop to root shell prompt, revert the changes you made.

Comment: Or if you couldn’t do it as @OrganicMarble says… go the quick way and install GDM … then fix LightDM later

Comment: Or reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @May I know how to get into recovery mode from grub?

Comment: @Raffa I'm not able to change or reconfigure dpkg since TTY is not showing up, I'm not able to run any command

Comment: Another way is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393) … after the `sudo chroot /mnt/` you can install and do what you want with your system.

Comment: For further Experiments use virtualbox or something else there you van make easy Backups before you try to shred your Ubuntu, s.c.n.r

Comment: @Raffa My issue was gettng into the TTY, after I was able to do that putting init=/bin/bash into linux line in GNU GRUB and hitting F10 I was able to get it, but no root access. After tons of research I found anothr commnd to get into maintenance mode from theGRUB as root and then I was able to make some changes so my system  cancame back as normal. Just putting single at the end of linux will get u there, enter to maintenance mode,  u can make proper changes,  run dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 to set greeter to default one and I was good to go. I'm writing this comment from Linux now =D

Comment: @nobody From now on I will get a snapshot of the sys everytime iḿ making some changes lol

Comment: Use btrfs as filesystem when choosing to do snapshots. It saves time and space when creating a snapshot