# Can't update ubuntu after closing computer while updating kernel

Tags: apt, dpkg, 22.04, 18.10

What can I do to normally update my system (Ubuntu). By acident I shutdown my PC while updating a linux-kernel package, also I think at time of update my Ubuntu start to updating from old 18 vesion to 22 version. I tried this command, but have no result:

sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt-get upgrade -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
>>> sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 duplicity : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 hplip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 kitty : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perlapi-5.30.0 but it is not installable
 python2 : PreDepends: python2-minimal (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4) but 2.7.18-3 is installed
           Depends: libpython2-stdlib (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4) but 2.7.18-3 is installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.6-1~22.04 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.6-1~22.04 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-cffi-backend : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-cups : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
               Breaks: python3 (< 3.9.2-1~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.10.5-0~)
 python3-gdbm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10.5-0~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-greenlet : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-ldb : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.10.5-0~)
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-msgpack : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-netifaces : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-pyqt5.sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-renderpm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-simplejson : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-talloc : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-uno : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 usb-creator-gtk : Depends: usb-creator-common (= 0.3.13) but 0.3.7 is installed
 virtualbox : Depends: python3 (>= 3.10~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

>>> sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  app-install-data-partner bsdmainutils ca-certificates-java clangd-10
  default-jre default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra g++-9 gcc-10-base
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
  gir1.2-handy-0.0 gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-screenshot icu-devtools
  java-common ldap-utils libamtk-5-0 libamtk-5-common libaom0
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libboost-date-time1.71.0
  libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libboost-locale1.71.0
  libboost-thread1.71.0 libcamel-1.2-62 libcbor0.6 libcdio18 libcmis-0.5-5v5
  libcodec2-0.9 libdecor-0-0 libdecor-0-plugin-1-cairo libdns-export1109
  libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libextutils-pkgconfig-perl
  libgnome-bg-4-1 libgsoap-2.8.91 libgupnp-1.2-0 libhogweed5 libicu-dev
  libidn11 libigdgmm11 libilmbase24 libisl22 libjson-c4 libjsoncpp1
  libjuh-java libjurt-java liblibreoffice-java liblldb-14 libmozjs-68-0
  libmysqlclient21 libneon27-gnutls libnettle7 libnfsidmap1 libntfs-3g883
  libopenexr24 liborcus-0.15-0 libpam-pwquality libperl5.30 libphonenumber7
  libpoppler97 libprotobuf17 libpython3.8-dev libqpdf26
  libreoffice-style-tango libridl-java libsdl2-2.0-0 libsnmp35 libtcl8.6
  libtepl-4-0 libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0
  libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 libunoloader-java libvpx6 libx264-155 libx265-179
  libxml2-dev ltrace lz4 mysql-common ncal openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless perl-modules-5.30 pkg-config popularity-contest
  python3-entrypoints python3-neovim python3-packaging
  python3-requests-unixsocket python3-simplejson python3-sip python3.8
  python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy
  ure-java vino xul-ext-ubufox
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  liblocale-gettext-perl linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic python2 python3
  usb-creator-common
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools python2-doc python-tk
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  liblocale-gettext-perl linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic python2 python3
  usb-creator-common
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.
1347 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 60.4 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up dpkg (1.21.1ubuntu2.1) ...
head: error reading 'dpkg': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package dpkg (--configure):
 installed dpkg package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of perl-base:
 perl-base depends on dpkg (>= 1.17.17); however:
  Package dpkg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package perl-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on dpkg (>= 1.13.20); however:
  Package dpkg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message ind
icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered whil
e processing:
 dpkg
 perl-base
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


>>> sudo apt-get upgrade -f
.........................
head: error reading 'dpkg': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package dpkg (--configure):
 installed dpkg package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of perl-base:
 perl-base depends on dpkg (>= 1.17.17); however:
  Package dpkg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package perl-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on dpkg (>= 1.13.20); however:
  Package dpkg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 dpkg
 perl-base
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


>>> sudo dpkg --configure -a
........
dpkg: error processing package {PACKAGE_NAME} (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
.........
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-distutils
 hplip
 python3-dbus
 system-config-printer-common
 python3-cairo:amd64
 python3-renderpm:amd64
 python3-setuptools
 usb-creator-gtk
 python3-gdbm:amd64
 python3-talloc:amd64
 python3-apt
 python3-aptdaemon
 update-notifier-common
 rhythmbox-plugins
 update-manager
 samba-libs:amd64
 python3-yaml
 kitty
 python3
 linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic
 python3-zipp
 python3-click
 python3-xdg
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-markupsafe
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 openprinting-ppds
 software-properties-common
 apport
 python3-tz
 python3-cliapp
 python3-apport
 netplan.io
 python3-cupshelpers
 python3-six
 python3-simplejson
 ibus-table
 python3-pil:amd64
 python3-cups:amd64
 python3-oauthlib
 python3-chardet
 python3-secretstorage
 python3-pyparsing
 python3-software-properties
 system-config-printer
 python3-certifi
 gnome-tweaks
 python3-pexpect
 python3-cryptography
 python3-wadllib
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.

>>> cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220831)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` in its current state and please tell us if you have manually modified that file previously.

Comment: @Raffa, I added what you asked for

Comment: Please follow the steps in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393 to fix the broken update from a live USB and see if it helps

Comment: Interrupting a release-upgrade is perhaps worst action you could possibly do to an Ubuntu system short of smashing it with a boulder. @Raffa's excellent link will help you...if help is possible at all. Sometimes the damage is un-recoverable and requires a complete reinstall.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 had one intended upgrade path; to the next release which was Ubuntu 19.04, but that closed when it went EOL. There is no upgrade path from 18.04 to 22.04; it was not QA-tested & not supported.  Why not re-install (*dirty or clean; clean if server install*) & then restore your data?  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS had an upgrade path to the next LTS release (20.04) but that wasn't available to 18.10; but at *best* that's the only upgrade path I'd try (*and expect possible*), not direct to 22.04 - so I'd check your details.  I'd also use `apt full-upgrade` and not the `apt upgrade`.