# Update failed now cant update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, 22.04

My PC got stopped while updating. Now whenever I am giving the command "sudo apt upgrade" I am getting the below mentioned error. I can not even open the GUI based software update. Can anyone please suggest what to do? I am having ubuntu 22.04 LTS

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-35 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Failed upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 "Please update the microcode"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238355)

Answer (score 2):

I finally downloaded the "linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-35_5.19.0-35.36_22.04.1_all.deb" package from internet. And then install it from the locally via "sudo dpkg -i //PATH_of_the_package//"
The had to run "apt --fix-broken install" to correct the dependencies.

Thank you all.