# Nvidia install built new kernel with no networking. How do I get back to a previous kernel?

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, cuda

I have a MSI MS-1653 laptop which was running Ubuntu 20.04.  I tried to install NVidia CUDA with `sudo apt install cuda`. For some reason the install built a new kernel, and now when I boot into that kernel I have no networking.

I need to roll back to a previous kernel, but I can't get the boot menu that will allow me to go to Advanced options and boot a previous kernel as shown [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/740797/how-to-roll-back-the-kernel-in-linux/).

When I try to remove the latest kernel with `sudo apt remove linux-image-5.15.0-1032-oracle` it fails because it can't connect to the internet.

MSI and Nvidia have left me with an unusable laptop.  Is there a way out of this predicament?

Comment: One way is `chroot` from a live system: https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393/968501

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) However, it's unlikely that your assumptions are correct. Nvidia can't change your kernel. It's possible that you had a minor kernel patch at the same time you had other updates, but they aren't related. Be careful trying to fix something that might not be the actual problem or you might just make things worse.

Comment: @Nmath - I can't use the GRUB menu because the MSI doesn't display it.  It just starts the linux boot sequence.  And that's one heck of a minor kernel patch that builds a kernel with no networking.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information about the problem at this point to jump to *any* conclusions about a cause or solution, but we can say what it *isn't*. So I'm trying to say that your theory about the cause of the problem is very unlikely. It is additionally concerning if you can not get to a GRUB menu because GRUB is a low level utility that runs before your graphics adapter and even before the kernel is loaded. This would indicate an entirely different problem that is unrelated to Nvidia *or* the kernel that needs to be solved before you can do anything else.

Comment: Did you try pressing and holding the `shift` key during boot to access Grub menu? If that doesn’t work, perhaps pressing and holding the `esc` key? You may have to wait until after the bios splash screen. If neither of these, then do what @Raffa says and chroot into your system via Live disc and look at your grub configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that during the failed install there were messages that showed that there weren't enough  inotify max_user_watches.  Maybe this explains why I ended up with a crippled kernel.

I ended up having to install Ubuntu 22.04 to get my laptop back.

While installing Cuda on the new OS I did notice that it does a kernel build, so that is part of a normal Cuda install.  The NVidia driver and Cuda are working correctly now.