# GUI doesn't show up after a failed upgrade

Tags: boot, nvidia, upgrade, mount, gui

I got a prompt to update my Ubuntu version from 20.04 to 22.04. I chose to upgrade, but the upgrade failed for some unknown reasons (most probably it couldn't update my NVidia drivers). I was seeing no internet connectivity in my laptop, so I force restarted it.

No GUI comes now, and every restart takes me to emergency mode. I have never faced such an issue. This is what happens during boot now.[image: boot]

`sudo apt-get update` doesn't work now, because Ubuntu cannot connect to the Internet anymore. [image: update]

I tried `fsck` on every partition, but nothing got solved.[image: fsck]

Even I tried fsck on home partition explicitly using `fsck -f -y`, but no result.[image: home]

I tried reinstalling ubuntu desktop, but it failed.[image: desktop]

lsblk and fstab don't show any mismatch in UUID either.[image: uuid]

I tried `sudo apt autoremove`. A lot of packages got removed, but the main problem didn't get solved.

I am getting confused about what to do now.

Comment: Related ... [Failed upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 "Please update the microcode"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238355)

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238355/failed-upgrade-from-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-04-please-update-the-microcode), I created a bootable USB of Ubuntu 20.04. Then I booted using that USB and selected "Try Ubuntu". This enabled me to use an internet connection. My root folder was in partition /dev/sda2, so I mounted it using the steps mentioned in the answer. Now I got access to the root folder.

`apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` cannot resolve conflicts, so I had to execute `aptitude install ubuntu-desktop`. I allowed the time necessary to resolve all the conflicts. Thus ubuntu-desktop was installed. Now I executed `apt update` and `apt upgrade` (You may need to execute `apt autoremove` too).

Now it's time to exit and unmount. I followed the steps outlined in the answer to the question I have previously mentioned.