# Ubuntu 22.04 not booting, after "sudo apt purge gnome-shell-commen"

Tags: boot, apt, upgrade, gnome-shell, purge

After upgrade from 18.04lts to 22.04lts, everything was ok except the screen saver did not worked. Surfed the net to sort this problem out. I accepted the advice go to the therminal write "sudo apt purge gnome-shell-commen" restarted, then i got this.

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 412869/2338336 files, 6126517/9339904 bloks
71.5198121 rtl18192se: switch case 0x5e not processed
```

Then tried Ubuntu,  Linux 5.4.0-148-generic (recovery mode) and Resume normal boot.

Got this:

```
Ubuntu 20*.04.6 LTS oryx-EasyNote-TM86 tty1
oryx-EasyNote-TM86 login:
```

*This is buzz me because as far as i know i'm sure i was upgrading to 22.04.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no package called `gnome-shell-commen` ... You probably meant `gnome-shell-common` and that was a typo.

Answer (score 4):

#### What happened?

This happened:

```
$ apt -s purge gnome-shell-common
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  notification-daemon policykit-1-gnome
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chrome-gnome-shell* gdm3* gnome-shell* gnome-shell-common*
  gnome-shell-extension-appindicator* gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng*
  gnome-shell-extension-manager* gnome-shell-extension-prefs*
  gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor* gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock*
  gnome-shell-extensions* gnome-tweaks* ubuntu-desktop*
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal* ubuntu-session*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  notification-daemon policykit-1-gnome
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 15 to remove and 30 not to upgrade.
Purg chrome-gnome-shell [10.1-5]
Purg ubuntu-desktop [1.481]
Purg ubuntu-desktop-minimal [1.481]
Purg gdm3 [42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.2]
Purg gnome-shell-extension-prefs [42.5-0ubuntu1]
Inst policykit-1-gnome (0.105-7ubuntu3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
Inst notification-daemon (3.20.0-4build1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
Purg gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor [40-1]
Purg gnome-shell [42.5-0ubuntu1] [gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 ubuntu-session:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-manager:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 ]
Purg gnome-tweaks [42~beta-1ubuntu2] [gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 ubuntu-session:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-manager:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 ]
Purg gnome-shell-common [42.5-0ubuntu1] [gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 ubuntu-session:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-manager:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 ]
Purg gnome-shell-extension-appindicator [42-2~fakesync1] [gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 ubuntu-session:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-manager:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 ]
Purg gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng [43-2ubuntu1] [gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 ubuntu-session:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-manager:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 ]
Purg gnome-shell-extension-manager [0.3.0-0ubuntu2.1] [gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 ubuntu-session:amd64 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 ]
Purg gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock [72~ubuntu5.22.04.1] [gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 ubuntu-session:amd64 ]
Purg gnome-shell-extensions [42.1-0ubuntu1] [ubuntu-session:amd64 ]
Purg ubuntu-session [42.0-1ubuntu2]
Conf policykit-1-gnome (0.105-7ubuntu3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
Conf notification-daemon (3.20.0-4build1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
```

The desktop environment's essential main meta-package(*`ubuntu-desktop`*) among other packages were removed.

#### How to fix?

Reinstall the removed packages starting with `ubuntu-desktop` i.e.:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

And so on.

If your system doesn't automatically boot to a terminal, then do that from [the recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) or from [a live system with `chroot`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393).

#### How to avoid this in the future?

Read the list of packages to be removed carefully before answering yes ... Needless to say you shouldn't arbitrarily follow anonymous advice on the internet to copy/paste and execute commands that you don't know their effect on your system.