# Computer doesn't start

Tags: boot, disk-usage, fsck

Since this morning my other desktop computer doesn't start anymore. It just shows what's on the screen photo. My husband started an update, but it couldn't finish because there wasn't enough space on the computer.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some details. Which version of Ubuntu is this? What was the last thing you did before this happened? Is this a laptop? A desktop?

Comment: You can [`chroot` from a live system](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393) and free some space then run the upgrade again.

Comment: chroot is one thing, but using Recovery mode might be as quick if it is possible to get into it. -> https://www.google.com/search?&q=recovery+mode+ubuntu - cleaning out e.g. old kernels might be one thing